# Build up a string as a format then use it as a format

Tags: vb.net, string, format

Is there a way to use a string as an IFormatProvider.

Something along the lines of this:

```
Dim MyValue As String = "1216,00"
Dim MyDecimalSymbol As String = "."
Dim Format As String = "00" & MyDecimalSymbol & Decimals
MyValue = MyValue.ToString(Format)
'Output should be 1216.00
```

Sadly the function doesn't accept a string and I have to build it up dynamically, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Your whole problem stems from the fact that you have a numeric value in a string. Where is this value coming from in the first place? Can't you just parse it into a numeric of the appropriate type?

Comment: Sadly that's not an option since we do some checks on the string itself as well and may need to replace some parts etc.

Comment: You need to expand your question to give a number of different inputs and the desired outputs for those inputs as it is not clear what you are trying to achieve as it stands

Answer (score 0):

You like to do this:

```
    Dim MyValue As Double = 1216.01
    Dim MyDecimalSymbol As String = "."
    Dim Decimals As String = "00"
    Dim Format As String = "00" & MyDecimalSymbol & Decimals
    Dim myStringValue As String
    myStringValue = MyValue.ToString(Format)
    Console.WriteLine(myStringValue)
    Console.ReadLine()
```

**BUT IT WILL NOT WORK AS YOU MAY EXPECT**

The decimal Point "." will be replaced by your currency settings (so it will work in US and other countries, but not in some european countries).

Comment: If you're not referencing culture anywhere it shouldn't and because you'll have to give toString an IFormatProvider it'll cause exception: " Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IFormatProvider'."

Comment: In my test code I did not reference any specific culture. The most important thing: you tried to format a string to a string, not a number to a string. For sure you can create your own format provider handling strings.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will replace the comma with the current culture decimal separator and format the value as you want, but there are no checks to make sure the value has a comma in it in the first place, so you may need to add that:

```
    Dim MyValue As String = "1216,00"
    Dim MyDecimalSymbol As String = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator
    Dim decimals = "00"
    MyValue = String.Format("{0:00}{1}{2}", MyValue.Split(","c)(0), MyDecimalSymbol, CInt(MyValue.Split(","c)(1)).ToString(decimals))
```

Comment: I can't check for an comma in a string since the input could also be 1216.00, 1,216.00 or 1.216,00

Comment: Well then you will have to know which locale each value is representing or else how can you possibly parse all of those? If this value is coming from a database, you should be storing it as a numeric value, not a string

Answer (score -1):

Allright thanks everyone for the advice, I used a different way to achieve what I want and that is this:

```
If Value.IndexOf(MyNumberGroupSymbol) <> -1 And Value.IndexOf(MyDecimalSymbol) = -1 Then
                If Value.Length - (Value.IndexOf(MyNumberGroupSymbol) + 1) = 1 Or Value.Length - (Value.IndexOf(MyNumberGroupSymbol) + 1) = 2 Then
                    'The group separator has been used instead of the decimal separator so the correct decimal separator will be set
                    Value = Value.Replace(MyNumberGroupSymbol, MyDecimalSymbol)
                End If
            End If
            If Double.TryParse(Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number, Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, 0) = True 
                If MyDecimalSymbol = "." Then
                    Dim MyDouble As Double = Double.Parse(Value, New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"))
                    MyValue = MyDouble.ToString("N" & Decimals, New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"))
                    'Decimals makes sure there are enough decimals after the decimal separator
                Else
                    Dim MyDouble As Double = Double.Parse(Value, New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nl-NL"))
                    MyValue = MyDouble.ToString("N" & Decimals, New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nl-NL"))
                End If
            End If
```